# Show table of database in sybase language

Tags: database, sybase

sybase language
Hello eveyone,
I have a problem i don't understand how to make a basic thing in sybase because i'm a beginner in this language.

I would like show table of a database in sybase but how can i do. I didn't understand the exemple in the official website. what's that "sp_help [ [ @objname = ] 'name' ]  " ?! Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @objname= is a parameter being passed into the stored procedure. Where it has 'name' you should replace that with your own table name.

But you don't actually need to do that you can just run the following (obviously replacing tablename with the name of your own table or object):

```
   sp_help <tablename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what it is you are trying to achieve. If you mean to describe a table in a database, then the above posted comment already answers that.

if you meant to actually show a table in terms of retrieving data within that table, then you need to look into the SELECT statement, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  <column1>
  ,<column2> 
FROM
  <tableName>
```

Comment: He said he was trying to run sp_help specifically he was just struggling with the example online, not a select statement.